# iOS 8 Custom Keyboard Extension crashing in Adhoc Provisioning Profiles

Tags: crash, ios8, custom-keyboard, ios8-extension

I had made a Custom Keyboard Extension for iOS 8 its working fine on Development Provisioning Profiles but crashes in Adhoc Provisioning Profiles.

Help me out to solve this issue.

```
Incident Identifier: BD7BAD52-333F-46EA-9624-24BF44960B9F
CrashReporter Key:   aa2131813342f267721baf2e7afd06cbd6d29fe8
Hardware Model:      iPod5,1
Process:             customkeyboard [18953]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/3FBE2213-2623-4A8A-A804-3B0F21BFA5CA/GifKeyConcept.app/PlugIns/customkeyboard.appex/customkeyboard
Identifier:          com.Rachit.customkeyboard.Extension
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-10-17 14:27:51.849 +0530
Launch Time:         2014-10-17 14:27:46.785 +0530
OS Version:          iOS 8.0.2 (12A405)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: LAUNCH_HANG
Exception Message: The extension took too much time to initialize
Highlighted Thread:  0

Backtrace not available

Unknown thread crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000000    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x00000000
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000000    sp: 0x0016fc34      lr: 0x00000000      pc: 0x1fe0a000
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
0x1fe09000 - 0x1fe2cfff dyld armv7  <6e778e287a303a9aaaf655849ae1d611> /usr/lib/dyld
```